# How to define two FK in the same table?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a table called `User` which inherit the properties from `IdentityUser`, inside that table I added a reference to the `UserFriendship` table which need to store all the user friendship:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserFriendship> UserFriendship { get; set; }
}
```

Essentially the `UserFriendship` contains two users, who are those who have a common friendship, this is the model definition:

```
public class UserFriendship
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("UserA")]
    public string UserAId { get; set; }
    public User UserA { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("UserB")]
    public string UserBId { get; set; }
    public User UserB { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I defined the `UserA` and the `UserB` which are two `FK` of a `User` that are contained inside `AspNetUsers` table.

Now inside the `FluentAPI` I declared the following:

```
builder.Entity<UserFriendship>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(f => f.Id);

    entity.HasOne(u => u.UserA)
          .WithMany(n => n.UserFriendships)
          .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserAId)
          .IsRequired();

    entity.HasOne(u => u.UserB)
          .WithMany(n => n.UserFriendships)
          .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserBId)
          .IsRequired();
 });
```

when I execute this command:

```
add-migration InitialMigration -context MyAppContext
```

I'll get:

> Cannot create a relationship between 'User.UserFriendships' and 'UserFriendship.UserB', because there already is a relationship between 'User.UserFriendships' and 'UserFriendship.UserA'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.

I'm not an expert of `EnityFramework`, but based on that error I think that I cannot define two `FK` in the same table?

Sorry for any mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can define more than one FK in table. 
The problem here is you are pointing two times to one navigation property - `UserFriendships`. The solution would be to create two navigation properties.

Navigation properties are used to browse the related data for specified foreign-key (you have one-to-many relationship) of entity.

Try this:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserFriendship> UserAFriendships { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserFriendship> UserBFriendships { get; set; }
}

public class UserFriendship
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserAId { get; set; }
    public User UserA { get; set; }

    public string UserBId { get; set; }
    public User UserB { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
 }
```

And define the relationship through fluent api as following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriendship>(entity =>
{
     entity.HasKey(f => f.Id);

     entity.HasOne(u => u.UserA)
         .WithMany(n => n.UserAFriendships)
         .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserAId)
         .IsRequired();

     entity.HasOne(u => u.UserB)
          .WithMany(n => n.UserBFriendships)
          .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserBId)
          .IsRequired();
});
```

What is more - you don't need to specify attributes `Key, ForeignKey` if you use Fluent API.

Comment: thanks this works, do you think my implementation is correct or there is another simple way to achieve this?